# assembly timer code [ C8051F340 ] explanation

Tags: microcontroller, timer, assembly

Hi my problem is that I cant understand this code when I test it on my microcontroller  Si Lab [ C8051F340 ]and let it run step by step 
[image]
My problem is basically is when I test the program on my microcontroller ( I dont feel confortable to post the whole program ) the program counter arrives to the instruction "jnb TF0, Innere_Schleife" and stops there . I can still see my microcontroller 7segment display changing . But I dont undertand why and how the program counter just stops there and doesnt jump to the next instruction although I can still see changes on my board .

Answer (score 2):

`JNB`,[Jump if Bit Not Set](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/comp/8051/set8051.html#51jnb), will jump to the label `Innere_Schleife` 
as long as the bit `TF0` is not set.

Since `Innere_Schleife` is right above `JNB`, this is a jump to itself. It will appear as if the cpu does not step becuase it doesn't update the program counter.

Comment: @PeterJ I can't answer that without either hardware or more software.